# How do I configure Git to automatically pull from origin on branch change?

Tags: git, branch, git-pull

When I switch branches, I'd like to always pull the latest changes from origin if local is clean and behind its origin counterpart. The local branch is a tracking branch of its remote branch, and fetch works as intended.

- Can Git be configured to do this automatically?
- Is there a repository-wide setting to do this for all branches? (Our branches are frequently created and deleted as company policy is one branch per task which is PR'd and merged when reviewed)

---

EDIT:

For context, I use Visual Studio 2017 and mostly its user interface to perform Git commands. There's no problem keeping Git up-to-date. There are a few Git commands that I need to do using the command-line, such as renaming a branch, or hidden repo settings.

When I say the "local is clean", yes that refers to the worktree from `git status`, and in VS where there are no outgoing commits or locally modified files. VS has a very nice UI which shows you this information in real-time.

By

> (Our branches are frequently created and deleted as company policy is
>   one branch per task which is PR'd and merged when reviewed)

This was supposed to be an off-hand way of saying "I really don't want to set this setting or hook up for every single branch", but the explanation is:

We create our own local branches split off of a master branch to fulfil a task. In VS, this is "Create local branch from..." which performs a checkout of the branch with the desired name.
Under the hood, I'm sure this is equivalent to `git checkout -b fillcatnip master`. `fillcatnip` is an untracked local branch until pushed to the remote, but it'll be pushed as a new branch `fillcatnip` rather than to the original `master`. At that point, it becomes a tracking branch and can be given a pull request (PR) to be merged back into `master` when the task has been completed.
BUT if `master` has moved on and conflicted before the PR can be fulfilled, then the branch cannot be merged until the conflicts have been resolved. By the time this happens, I may have already begun another task. Hence, if I save the task I'm currently on (commit & push, stash, whatever), then switch back to the conflicted branch, I'd like that branch's remote copy and not my own local copy, as somebody may have pushed changes to it while it's been awaiting merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to the two questions are "not exactly" and "no", but also "normally there's no need", and in fact, the question itself does not make a lot of sense as asked.  The first and largest problem lies in the phrase "if local is clean"—what, precisely, does this mean?

If "clean" refers to what `git status` reports:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

then "clean" refers to the *work-tree*, and sometimes perhaps to the *index*, as compared to each other and/or the `HEAD` commit.

Unless you use `git worktree add` to create auxiliary work-trees, there's only *one* work-tree (and one corresponding index) for any given Git repository.  (If you *do* use `git worktree add`, each added work-tree is on its own separate branch.  That might in fact be the answer you are really looking for, here.)

Let's note here as well that a branch *name* like `master` or `feature` denotes one particular commit, which Git calls the *tip* commit of that branch.  There are other meanings for the word "branch": see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  But when you have a branch checked out, what this implies is that you have one particular *commit* checked out as well.  That commit's contents fill the index and the work-tree.

The command that switches branches—or to a "detached HEAD"—is `git checkout`.  It accomplishes the branch-switching (or HEAD-detaching) by writing, into the index and the work-tree, whatever is needed to achieve the switch from the commit you had checked-out before, to the commit you will have checked-out now.  If the work-tree was clean *before* the `git checkout`, this is always possible, and the work-tree will be clean *after* the `git checkout` as well.

If the work-tree is *not* clean before the `git checkout`, it's sometimes, but not always, still possible to switch branches: see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).  In that case, the work-tree will generally also be not-clean *after* the `git checkout` has switched branches.  The not-clean-ness will be because the checkout, when switching branches, did not have to update the index and work-tree entries for the files that did not match the commit that you had checked out just before you ran `git checkout branchname`.

#### Checking if the work-tree is clean

With the above out of the way, note that [`git-sh-setup`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh), a script that is available to other Git scripts, includes [a function named `require_clean_work_tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-sh-setup.sh#L210-L262).  You can examine this code, or simply use it, to determine whether a work-tree is clean.

You can combine this with [phd's answer about using a post-checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833118/1256452) to do the check and, if appropriate, run `git merge` or `git fetch && git merge`.  (I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely: break it down into its two separate steps like this.  Your life will be happier afterward.)

#### Why I suspect you should not need this at all

> (Our branches are frequently created and deleted as company policy is one branch per task which is PR'd and merged when reviewed)

As a general rule, if you're not going to *work* on a named branch (make new commits on it), you should not create it in the first place.  Having not created it, you never need to worry about updating it either.

Suppose, for instance, that you have a repository with one remote named `origin`, and on `origin`, there are branches for various tasks.  You want to *inspect* `origin/task/feedkittens` occasionally, but *work on* the (single) task `task/fillcatnip`.

In this case, to *inspect* things, go ahead and use the "detached HEAD" mode:

```
git checkout origin/task/feedkittens
```

To *work on things*, use `git checkout` to *create* `task/fillcatnip` *from* `origin/task/fillcatnip`:

```
git checkout task/fillcatnip
```

This works because `git checkout` will, if you ask it to check out a branch that *doesn't exist*, search for an `origin/` branch that otherwise has the same name.  If so, it will *create* the local branch such that the branch tip commit is the same as the remote-tracking name's commit.  At the same time, it will set up the local branch to *track* (have as its upstream) the remote-tracking name.

By creating the local branch name, you can now create new commits.  These will make the local branch

By avoiding creating `task/feedkittens`, you can just run `git fetch` and `git checkout origin/task/feedkittens` to see the latest.  You will be in "detached HEAD" mode, so it's usually a bad idea to create *new* commits now, but this means there's no need to drag around a local branch.

When the branch named `task/feedkittens` is deleted on `origin`, you can have your own remote-tracking name get deleted automatically during `git fetch` by setting:

```
git config fetch.prune true
```

As soon as you `git checkout` some other commit or name, you stop being detached-HEAD on the `origin/task/feedkittens` commit that no longer has a name.

If you want to work on (as in "add commits to") multiple different branches simultaneously, consider using `git worktree add`, as long as your Git is at least version 2.5.  Each added work-tree has its own private index, but all the added work-trees share the single underlying repository.  If your Git is too old, consider just making separate clones for each branch you want to work on at once.

Comment: Hi torek, I've written an edit to the question for clarity. Thank you for the detailed answer and advice

Comment: Aha. VS may prevent you from using `git worktree add`, but normally that would be what *I* would suggest as the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) — in your case it's [post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout). In the hook you call `git pull`.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

prev_HEAD="$1"
new_HEAD="$2"
new_branch="$3"

if [ "$new_branch" = 1 ]; then
    git pull origin "$new_HEAD"
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: What is that "1" there? Wasn't supposed to be "master" instead?

Comment: See the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout Please note **flag=0/1**.